# how to add current date to existing table?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I add current date to existing table for each row??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER tableName ADD (DateField DATE);
UPDATE tableName SET DateField = CURDATE();
```

If you want the current time also, change `Date` to `DATETIME` & `CURDATE()` to `NOW()`

Note: If you are using php (as tagged in the question) It may be quicker to alter the table **with** the current time:

```
$dtFormatted = date("Y-m-d"); //php code

ALTER tableName ADD (DateField DATE DEFAULT '{$dtFormatted}');
ALTER tableName MODIFY DateField DATE DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `table` set `date` = NOW();
```